# How can I proof that f(x) is not pointwise convergence? And How can I draw this function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

How can I prove that $f(x)$ is not pointwise convergent? And how can I draw this function?

$$
f_n(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&nx &&: 0 \ge x \ge \frac{1}{n}\\
&2-nx &&: \frac{1}{n} \ge x \ge \frac{2}{n}\\
&0 &&: \frac{2}{n} \ge x \ge 1
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

Comment: Are you sure you copied the third line of the definition of $f_n$ correctly? Did you mean to ask about pointwise convergence of $f_n$ rather than of $f(x)f(x)$?

Comment: You right Blass, that was mistake. It should be f_n(x) = 0

Comment: $f_n(\frac 1n) = 1$ for all $n.$  The functions starts at 0, rises to 1, falls back to 0 and is a flat line thereafter.  The party hat on the left hand side get steeper and steeper as $n$ becomes large.

Comment: You can find picture showing the functions in this question: [Convergence and uniform convergence of a sequence of functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/795729).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
$$f_n(0)=0$$

for $x>0$ and large enough $n$, $\frac{2}{n}<x \implies f_n(x)=0$.

The pointwise limit is zero.